# How do I hide "Empty" results in Angular 2 Kendo UI Sortable?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am using [Angular 2 Kendo UI Sortable](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/) in my app to display some dynamically-generated lists of values. Sometimes, the list is empty. Kendo insists on displaying a big ugly "Empty", and I can't understand how to get rid of it.

```
                     <kendo-sortable [navigatable]="true" [data]="newTree | treeBuilder:item.id">
                      <ul>
                        <ng-template *ngIf="item" let-item="item"> // Nope this doesn't work.
                          <li>
                            <div class="child-2">{{item}}</div>
                          </li>
                        </ng-template>
                      </ul>
                    </kendo-sortable>
```

Comment: try put ` *ngIf="item" ` on `li` element

Comment: Thanks, tried that: same result unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it is actually mentioned in [the docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/api/SortableComponent/). There are 3 relevant attributes:

> **emptyItemClass**
>
> *Defines the class which is applied to the empty item when the Sortable has empty data.*
>
> **emptyItemStyle**
>
> *Defines the CSS styles applied to an empty item.*
>
> **emptyText**
>
> *Sets the text message that will be displayed when the Sortable has no items.*

Setting the empty text to "" simply makes it default to "Empty" again. So the solution I found is to use the `emptyItemStyle` attribute and specify `display:none`, and that's finally got rid of it. Phew.

Stupid feature. Why not just leave it up to users to specify their own custom content if they need it using template conditionals?...

Comment: Glad you found it. You should accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will do, for some reason SO makes me wait 2 days until I can do so though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `item` is an `Array`, try `*ngIf="item.length > 0"`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Not working either I'm afraid (that's using `*ngIf="item.length > 0"` on the `li`). Whatever I do, Kendo just insists on displaying "Empty" in the template. It's infuriating. Absolutely nothing about it in the docs either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
...
<kendo-sortable [navigatable]="true" [data]="newTree | treeBuilder:item.id" [emptyText]="''">
</kendo-sortable>
...
```

with

> [emptyText]="''"

you can custom your message for empty result or put it empty like me, it will not show empty again.